# How to lock an Android app so it can't be closed?

Tags: android, html, native

I'm looking for a way(native/HTML5/jQuery) to lock an application so it can't be closed.
I'm well aware that this is not user friendly.

The point is for an administrator of a device to lock an application, by password/pin/pattern, to prevent a user from leaving this application.

Any ideas are appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: could you be more specific on what it is you want to do?

Comment: Sort of what Toddler Lock does, but with authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that this question is to be applied in a closed environment application, meaning it won't be on the Google Play or available to the mass audience in any way).

I've done such type of application before and probably the most direct way is to make a Launcher app, that way the Home button click will be delivered to it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can make such an app is by making a launcher that requires authentication to allow the user to use the rest of the apps. In any other kind of app, the user will always be able to exit using the home button.

Comment: Thanks! I hoped there was another solution but this will do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't lock your activity in such way because system controls its state. You can manage power state, screen, but you can't and shouldn't froze your activity and forbid opening another applications.

Even if you find solution for that there is a simple case: user reboots device and your lock doesn't work.